# find characters in a url using RegExp

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

"/products/watch"

for the string above I'm  only trying to match the backslashes and the characters that in between them. so in this case i only want to match /products/

what will be the base way to do this with RegExp or can I use Jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var str = "/products/watch";
var matches = str.match(/\/(.*?)\//);
if (matches) {
    // matches[0] is the full match including slashes "/products/"
    // matches[1] is the chars between the slashes "products"
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/8AAAE/